# Scilab atoms error package not registered

Tags: scilab

Is there a common solution for installation error in atoms install?

--> atomsSystemUpdate()
Scanning repository http://atoms.scilab.org/6.0 ... Done

--> atomsInstall("wgserialxcosio")
atomsInstallList: The package "wgserialxcosio" is not registered.
Please check on the ATOMS repository that it is available for Scilab 6.0 on Windows.
If it is, run atomsSystemUpdate() before trying atomsInstall(..) again.

at line    52 of function atomsError       ( C:\Tools\scilab-6.0.2\modules\atoms\macros\atoms_internals\atomsError.sci line 66 )
at line    78 of function atomsInstallList ( C:\Tools\scilab-6.0.2\modules\atoms\macros\atoms_internals\atomsInstallList.sci line 117 )
at line   233 of function atomsInstall     ( C:\Tools\scilab-6.0.2\modules\atoms\macros\atomsInstall.sci line 249 )

--> ver
ans  =

```
     column 1
```

!Scilab Version:                     !
!                                    !
!Operating System:                   !
!                                    !
!Java version:                       !
!                                    !
!Java runtime information:           !
!                                    !
!Java Virtual Machine information:   !
!                                    !
!Vendor specification:               !

```
     column 2
```

!6.0.2.1550134035                                                  !
!                                                                  !
!Windows 10 10.0                                                   !
!                                                                  !
!1.8.0_151                                                         !
!                                                                  !
!Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)             !
!                                                                  !
!Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)  !
!                                                                  !
!Oracle Corporation                                                !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toolbox page https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/wgserialxcosio/16.04.1 says that it is not available for recent versions of Scilab (for Windows you need Scilab <= 5.5.2). Please request toolbox rebuild on https://scilab.discourse.group (Atoms category).

Comment: -->atomsInstall("wgserialxcosio")
atomsInstallList: Das Paket wgserialxcosio ist nicht verfügbar.
 !--error 10000 

at line      51 of function atomsError called by :  
at line      76 of function atomsInstallList called by :  
at line     233 of function atomsInstall called by :  
atomsInstall("wgserialxcosio")
 
 
-->ver
 ans  =
 
!Scilab Version:             5.4.1.1364571296

Comment: I tried, but scilab 5.4.1 Windows x64 is not working, too

Comment: OK, good news, the repackaging will be quite simple.

Comment: Manually installation is working with Scilab Version 5.4.1 x64 Windows atomsInstall("C:\Downloads\wgserialxcosio_16.04.1_5.5-2.bin.x64.windows.zip")

Comment: Hello Stéphane, unfortunatley there are many toolboxes in the Atoms Modulmanager that are not able to be installed in Scilab 2023. How can I help, to update these modules?

Comment: It seema that Scilab 6.1.1 is the best version, that supports most toolboxes. Unfortunatly wgserialxcosio got an error:
Error while creating the directory. 'C:Tools\SCILAB~2.1\contrib\wgserialxcosio\16.04.1\'

Comment: Installation with Scilab 6.0 is possible but after restarting scilab you get the error "lib: Old binary lib detected. Please recompile it for Scilab 6."

Comment: I updated the toolbox, please interact in the dedicated Scilab discourse thread: https://scilab.discourse.group/t/toolbox-rebuild-xcos-to-serial-port/

Comment: @kwas-poser : it was just recompiled a quarter of an hour ago. Installation and use with Scilab 6.0 and 6.1 is now possible as well. Please retry.

Comment: Thank you for updating! https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/wgserialxcosio